# "=" at the end of a message digest

Tags: java, base64, sha1

Why is there an `"="` sign at the end of a sha1 message digest?(after it is base64 encoded)
The `"="` sign appears even at the end of a base64 endcoded signature(rsa). Why does base 64 include it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just part of base64 - nothing to do with digests. The "=" are added for padding, so that the overall result is always a multiple of four characters, but readers can tell when a four character "block" only represents one or two bytes (rather than the normal three).

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding) for more information. (Note that while it says padding is only required in some situations, I don't think I've ever seen a base64 encoder which *doesn't* include the padding, at least by default. It's far more common to include padding than not to do so.)

Comment: @Ashwin See more about padding in Base64: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov: Was just adding that link myself :)

Comment: Yea it has nothing to do with digest as Jon Skeet said.

Comment: @Konstantin V. Salikhov : Thanks for the link it explained a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The '==' sequence indicates that the last group contained only 1 byte, and '=' indicates that it contained 2 bytes.